# Restoring /home/etc to /etc

Tags: centos, filesystems, backup

I need to copy backup files from `/mnt/backup/etc` to `/etc`
so `cp/mnt/backup/etc*` is the command I am thinking of.

However, experience is teaching me `cp/mnt/backup/etc*` may be a destructive command to the filesystem because there maybe differences in files from repos that are not on this fresh install of CentOS7 version but are in `/mnt/backup/etc*` or other differences I am not aware of.

I am thinking of a command that will compare files of both directories and output if a difference in the file exists.  From there I can determine which files from `/mnt/backup/etc` to not restore if any.

Not sure how to do this, it's been a while.  I think I use the `wc` command to output the difference between the files but not certain on how to compare the differences between two files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several options to perform a comparison beforehand:

- `rsync`

  Running `rsync` with the `-n` flag will first perform a "dry run" that enables you to see what files would be copied, so that you can make manual adjustments if necessary.

  ```
  rsync -nvahHSEi /mnt/backup/etc/* /etc
  ```

  would be the dry run, and will also output more information on *why* a certain file would need copying (difference in size/modification date ...). If the differences are trivial enough, you could just re-run the command without the `n` to perform the actual "restore" operation fully automatic.
- `diff`

  You can run `diff` not only with two files, but also with two *directories* as argument, and it will show you which files differ, where their contents differ (at least for text files), and which ones are only present in one of the two paths. Use with the `-r` option to recursively descend into subdirectories. As noted by @Olivier Dulac, you could first run `diff -q` on the directories to display only a list of differing files (without the actual difference).
- `meld`

  This is a GUI-based comparison tool which will also allow you to determine the difference between two directories.

Comment: for diff, start with -q to just see the list of filess/dirs that differ and not the lines of files that are different:  `diff -q --recursive /path/to/dir1 /path/to/dir2` will show the summary of differences of those 2 directories (and compare subdirs of the same names as well), listing only if this or that file or directory differ (not how they differ).